# NextJS not setting state on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am having issues with my NextJS app. I am trying to display a class (loading spinner) to a button when it tries to log a user in. I am doing this by setting the `loading` state to true before it calls the login function, and then set the state to false after its done (in the `submitForm` function), but it doesn't seem to be setting it. Whenever i click the button the state stays at `false`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import { useAuth } from '@/hooks/auth'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ButtonSpinner from '@/styles/buttonspinner.module.css'

export default function Home() {
    const router = useRouter()

    const { login } = useAuth({
        middleware: 'guest',
        redirectIfAuthenticated: '/dashboard',
    })

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState([])
    const [status, setStatus] = useState(null)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (router.query.reset?.length > 0 && errors.length === 0) {
            setStatus(atob(router.query.reset))
        } else {
            setStatus(null)
        }
    })

    const submitForm = async event => {
        event.preventDefault()

        setLoading(true)
        login({ email, password, setErrors, setStatus })
        setLoading(false)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form className="mt-8 space-y-6" onSubmit={submitForm} autoComplete="off">
                <button className={"shadow-sm relative w-full " + (loading ? ButtonSpinner['btn-loading'] : "")}>
                    Sign in
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not waiting for login response

```
const submitForm = async event => {
  event.preventDefault()
  setLoading(true)
  try {
     await login({ email, password, setErrors, setStatus });
  } finally {
    setLoading(false)    
  }
}
```